# How to set outerHTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a UserControl. Ex:

```
<div id="divItem">
some html
</div>
```

The ajax request return new html of this UC from server. Ex:

```
<div id="divItem">
    new html
</div>
```

I want to replace the old html by the new one. How could I do that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)?

Comment: If you include the starting and ending tags, it's called `outerHTML`. The part you want to replace is `innerHTML`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**If you also return the div divItem**

```
$("#divItem").replaceWith("NEW HTML");
```

Put the new HTML on the spot or replace the innerHTML, since they got the same container:

```
$("#divItem").html($("NEW HTML").html());
```

**If you dont return the div divItem**

Just put the new html:

```
$("#divItem").html("NEW HTML");
```

Comment: @roman Yes, because if I see yours, mine wans't the best way, and I like to provide a complete correct answer. But you got a +1.

Comment: You should cleanup this answer is it offers two answers when Jin was looking to replace old html with new.  You should emphasize with .replaceWith and you'll get my +1

Answer (score 19):

I guess [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is what you search.

```
$('#divItem').replaceWith(serverResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing data from AJAX calls into a DOM element can be done using `.load()`.

```
$('#divItem').load('somePage.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace 1 item with multiple items. You can try:

```
var item_1 = $('<div>').text('item 1');
var item_2 = $('<div>').text('item 2');
var item_3 = $('<div>').text('item 3');

// 1/.
// dont' use this way because it's hard to read
$('#divItem').prop('outerHTML', item_1.prop('outerHTML') + item_2.prop('outerHTML') + item_3.prop('outerHTML'));

// 2/.
// dont' use this way because it's same to the first's
$('#divItem')[0].outerHTML = item_1.prop('outerHTML') + item_2.prop('outerHTML') + item_3.prop('outerHTML');

// 3/.
// if you use this way, how can we continue replace "#divItem" with "item_2"?
var obj = $('#divItem').replaceWith(item_1);

// "replaceWith" returns an object which was replaced with "item_1"
// there is no way to continue with "item_2" and "item_3"
// sure, if you DON'T want to write a new line
item_1.after(item_2);

// or
item_2.insertAfter(item_1);

// 4/.
// if we write this, the result should be: "item 3item 2item 1"
$('#divItem').after(item_1).after(item_2).after(item_3);

// so, the correct **inline** solution should be:
$('#divItem').after(item_3).after(item_2).after(item_1).remove();
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need

```
$('#divItem').html('new html');
```

This just replaces the div's innerHTML: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: This is `innerHTML`, we need `outerHTML`.